# UIActionSheet truncates long strings! Alternatives?

Tags: iphone, text, uiactionsheet

I have a UIActionSheet which gives the user a few standard choices. The text on the buttons, however, does not cleverly scale down like a text field though when there's too much-- it just truncates with an ellipsis.

I need to say a little more in on of my action sheet buttons than there's room for. I don't see any way of changing the action sheet's behavior, unfortunately. Any thoughts on alternatives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put some of the descriptive text in the UIActionSheet's `title` property, and then give just the verb or something concise in the button titles.

One alternative is: you might want to create a full-screen view that you show with `presentModalViewController:animated:`, where you have more space to show the text.

A third alternative is to create a UIView that animates up with UIButtons that you can customize, but doesn't fill the entire screen. I do that with some of my apps where the Settings are in a tab that slides up but doesn't need to cover the entire screen.